# how to disable full screen keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, tablelayout

I created a Table Layout and I don't want to have the keyboard editing view being fullscreen. I want to have the keyboard and the view behind it. Like when you send a message to somebody,you have the text fields with name,subject,etc and the keyboard .My Edit text is created dynamically,so I have to do this in code. I tried using SetImeOptions,  but using editview.SetImeOptions,is not working in Xamarin. Is there any way to do that in Xamarin? Thanks!

I want something like this: to view the entire table and if I want to write something, the keyboard to be with the table on screen(photo):
[image]

Not like this,where the keyboard is full screen:

[image]

I hope it is clear what I want..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Can you provide a screenshot? I looked at both the default email and messaging apps on my Nexus 4 and I don't see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using this:

```
public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
        {
            outAttrs.ImeOptions = ImeFlags.NoExtractUi;
            IInputConnection ret= base.OnCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);}
```

Comment: Its not working for my autocomplete control do you have any idea for this